# How to switch github account using git without deleting credentials in manage windows credentials manager?

Tags: git, github

I have been referring [this](https://youtu.be/aSTTJd5JMXg?t=158), whenever I want to add one of my project from one account repo(source) to another account repo(destination).

So I first do [this](https://github.community/t/adding-a-folder-from-one-repo-to-another/781/2). And when I try to push into the destination repo ( I have created another folder out of source folder for destination, where I have pulled stuff from destination repo before pushing ) it will give me the following error(as we can see in the video [here](https://youtu.be/aSTTJd5JMXg?t=131)):

```
remote: Permission to destination_userName/destination_Repo.git denied to source_Repo.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/dest_userName/dest_Repo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

After pull, configuring user.name, user.email, it still gives that error.

So I have been following solution from video but it is tiresome to delete credentials everytime and add again for both accounts. I also tried creating SSH Key and adding into destination github account. But that also not worked for me.

Is there any other solution to work it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Windows credential manager is working, `credential.helper` has been set to `manager`. To use another account, you could either add the account to the repository URL or specify `credential.username`. `foo` is the new account.

```
git push https://foo@github.com/dest_userName/dest_Repo.git bar
```

or

```
git -c credential.username=foo push origin bar
```

The first one is a bit troublesome if you need to type or paste the long URL every time. You could add a new remote for it,

```
git remote add baz https://foo@github.com/dest_userName/dest_Repo.git
git push baz bar
```

You mentioned you had created and added SSH key but it couldn't work. It could be because you still used the HTTPS URL (`origin`, aka `https://github.com/dest_userName/dest_Repo.git/`). Instead, the SSH URL is expected, which is `git@github.com:dest_userName/dest_Repo.git`.

```
git push git@github.com:dest_userName/dest_Repo.git bar
```

or

```
git remote add baz git@github.com:dest_userName/dest_Repo.git
git push baz bar
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I worked myself with your advise on SSH URL, and it worked. Thanks again, you saved a lot of time.